# What is the nearest World of Warcraft Server to the Philippines/Singapore?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have been playing world of warcraft for a long time, I remember the Oceanic servers being around 300ms still when I was playing a couple of years ago.

Right now I play around 200-250ms in Frostmourne, but this is still very high. I Ideally I want to play at around 80ms to at most 100ms else I will not even bother thinking about topping in PvP. I was able to reach around 2200-2400 rating back in the day in Gundrak at around 300ms, but at higher levels every millisecond counts and it's only a matter of time I hit a brick wall and lose to very good players

What server should people from South East Asia pick?

Comment: We don't recommend servers/realms, but you can have a look here: https://us.battle.net/forums/en/wow/topic/20757527709#post-3

Comment: Personally I don't see this as a recommendation request as much as a geographic (factual) question. Voted to re-open.

Comment: @TimS.I agree although I don't have the option to reopen. The question can easily be related to the latency and routing issues but it seems we're a bit uptight in this SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately location doesn't have much to do with latency, it all comes down to how your ISP chooses to route your connection to the AUS or US servers.

Lots of SEA players play on Oceanic servers due to the timezone and I believe that would be the best fit for you. Now if you're getting high latency to Frostmourne, there's a good chance your ISP is the problem.

I've gone through several posts on the WoW forums and noticed that it's usually the ISP's fault. [For example](https://us.forums.blizzard.com/en/wow/t/oceanic-routing-issue-from-south-east-asia/39013/2) one player's ISP routes the connection through some US backbone which causes the connection to route first to the USA and then back to Australia.

If the latency you're experiencing right now is too much, you have two options:

- you can report this to the [WoW technical forums](https://us.forums.blizzard.com/en/wow/c/support/technical-support) and post a [WinMTR](https://battle.net/support/article/000027780?utm_source=internal-TechForum&utm_medium=posting&utm_campaign=BlizzardCS&utm_content=solution). The CMs are really helpful and if your WinMTR provides any points of improvement for Blizzard's network, they will help.
- contact your ISP and provide as much info as you can (WinMTR) and ask them to correct the routing to Australia.

Unfortunately since each ISP works differently and latencies vary for US and Oceanic servers, it's mostly up to you test each server and find one with the lowest latency.

One last thing to note, since WoW works with sharding now, there's a good chance you will be ping-ponged around different servers - where while solo you might get 100ms, grouped 200ms (since you were transferred to the other players' server) and running a dungeon or arena game at 300ms.

Comment: There was a 3rd option where I used a service called WTFast. I dropped from very variable ping of 400 to 1000ms in Yojamba server to a stable 122ms. It does have a lot to do with routing since I live very far so the probabilities of inefficiencies such as bad routing increase over distance